# Ignorar el caso (mayúsculas o minúsculas) en parte del patrón de búsqueda en Vim

Tags: regex, vim

En la siguiente búsqueda en *Vim* me gustaría ignorar el caso de la primera letra:

```
/[tlcp]omo
```

Me gustaría saber cómo se puede ignorar el caso únicamente en la primera letra del patrón de búsqueda.

Vim tiene las siguientes opciones para ignorar el caso en el patrón de búsqueda:

```
:set ignorecase
:set smartcase [ignora caso si no hay ninguna mayúscula en la búsqueda]
```

ó usar `\c` en cualquier posición del patrón de búsqueda:

```
/hola\c  => [encuentra hola y HOLA]
```

Pero todas estas opciones ignoran el caso en el patrón entero, no en una parte.

Una opción para ignorar el caso de una sola letra del patrón de búsqueda consiste en, usando la colección `[]` de expresión regular, poner específicamente cada letra en mayúscula y minúscula:

```
/[tTlLcCpP]omo
```

Pero, **¿existe alguna forma de ignorar el caso en una parte del patrón de búsqueda sin tener que especificar todas y cada una de letras en mayúscula y minúscula usando expresión regular?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No parece que Vim lo permita**. Algunos lenguajes (PHP o Go por ejemplo) admiten en sus expresiones regulares la marca `(?i)` que significa que se ignore el caso desde el punto en que aparece en adelante, y también `(?-i)` que significa que no se ignore. Usando ambas podrías montar la expresión:

```
(?i)[tlpc](?-i)omo
```

que [como puedes ver en esta demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQQwDq/1) funciona como quieres.

En cambio Vim, lo más parecido que tiene, es el "carácter mágico" `\c` para ignorar el caso o `\C` para no ignorarlo. Pero no funcionan desde el punto en que aparecen en adelante, sino que, sin importar dónde aparezcan, afectan a la expresión regular completa. Por tanto esto no funciona: `\c[tlcp]\Como`. Tampoco restringen su efecto al grupo de captura en que aparezcan sino que afectan a la expresión regular completa, por lo que esto tampoco funciona: `\(\c[tlcp]\)\(\Como\)`.

Comment: Sí, [en este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2287440/2191572) ya daban una solución para el patrón de búsqueda completo, pero no una parte. Muchas gracias.

Comment: [Aquí (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60546551/6717386) comentan algo muy similar: **Vim no lo permite**.